# PERMISSION_DENIED: Dialogflow API has not been used in project 764086051850 before or it is disabled

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to run a sample code from (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) to detect intent with my agent (`g3-p3-chatbot-agent`).

But I am getting following error:

```
{ Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Dialogflow API has not been used in project 764086051850 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dialogflow.googleapis.com/overview?project=764086051850 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
at Object.exports.createStatusError (/Users/pnafria/Documents/Learn/JS/DialogFlow/ProjectServerSide/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/pnafria/Documents/Learn/JS/DialogFlow/ProjectServerSide/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/Users/pnafria/Documents/Learn/JS/DialogFlow/ProjectServerSide/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/Users/pnafria/Documents/Learn/JS/DialogFlow/ProjectServerSide/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
at callback (/Users/pnafria/Documents/Learn/JS/DialogFlow/ProjectServerSide/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
code: 7,
metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr:
{ 'google.rpc.help-bin': [Array], 'grpc-status-details-bin': [Array],
'grpc-server-stats-bin': [Array] } }, details: 'Dialogflow API has not been used in project 764086051850 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dialogflow.googleapis.com/overview?project=764086051850 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.' }
```

I am not sure why I am getting connected to this project number: `764086051850`. Can somebody help me to resolve this error?

Environment details:

OS: MacOS
Node.js version: 8.11.1
npm version: 6.0.1
dialogflow version: 0.6.0

Comment: If you're using an integration then you'll need to use the Dialogflow-Fulfillment library https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment

Comment: A bit late in getting to this but if you're encountering this issue, see: https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-oauth-credential-going-deeper-the-hard-way-f403cf3edf9d

Answer (score 4):

If you look closely at the error you will see the solution. Based on the [Dialogflow Node.js Client v2 README](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2), you need to enable the [Dialogflow API](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=dialogflow.googleapis.com) through Google Cloud Platform. From the GCP platform go to APIs & Services (left menu) > Dashboard > Enable APIs & Services > Enable Dialogflow API.

[image: Enable Dialogflow API] [image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to add the library from google console 
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/dialogflow then just enable the

After enabling you should get something like this:
[image: Image depicting library enabled]

Answer (score 0):

just add the library from google console

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/dialogflow.googleapis.com

Comment: What is the difference of your proposed solution to the one by Black Mamba? It seems so very similar.

Comment: That one needs a login, yours needs paying, I do not see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I still had this issue after enabling it on the google cloud website,
after researching https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/index.html
and setting up authentication with a service account
I implemented the code in their docs and took the 'private_key' and 'client_email' from the generated JSON key file, and it worked for me.

```
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({credentials:
      {
        private_key: '',
        client_email: ''
      }});
```